# Select column entries as one string

Tags: mysql, select, contacts

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `c` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`, `c`) VALUES
(1, 2, 3),
(4, 5, 6),
(7, 8, 9),
(10, 11, 12),
(13, 14, 15);
```

Which statement would be get out a string like this "1,4,7,10,13"?
I don't understand what one of contact functions i need, and how to use it right, i get anytime errors or wrong strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the function: `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a) AS result_list
FROM test
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  In this example, this would work.  Obviously you would probably need add a WHERE clause to it.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a)

FROM   test
```

Also if you wanted to do this for multiple groups you would want to use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a) FROM test;
```